# how to use Permutations and combination in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I have four different kinds of filters and they are select boxes: filter A, filter B, filter C and filter D. 
Each time, when an end-user update those selections, four arrays will be returned. Those returned results are filterAResultArr, filterBResultArr, filterCResultArr and filterDResultArr. 
If a user selects nothing from the selection box, an empty array will be returned.

```
//initiate
var filterAResultArr= [];
var filterBResultArr= [];
var filterCResultArr = [];
var filterDResultArr= [];
var filterSeResult = [];
```

What I want to achieve is below:

1. if there is one non-empty array returned

   if ( // in filterAResultArr, filterBResultArr, filterCResultArr and filterDResultArr, there is only one array is not empty)
     { filterSeResult = (the filter result which is not empty.) }

   if(filterAResultArr && !filterBResultArr && !filterCResultArr && !filterDResultArr){
   filterSeResult = filterAResultArr 
   }

   if(!filterAResultArr && filterBResultArr && !filterCResultArr && !filterDResultArr){
   filterSeResult = filterAResultArr 
   }

   if(!filterAResultArr && !filterBResultArr && filterCResultArr && !filterDResultArr){
   filterSeResult = filterAResultArr 
   }

   if(!filterAResultArr && !filterBResultArr && !filterCResultArr && filterDResultArr){
   filterSeResult = filterAResultArr 
   }
2. if there are only two non-empty arrays returned
3. if there are three non-empty arrays returned
4. if there are four non-empty arrays returned

Is there any way can make the code logical and not checking every single condition? It will look really stupid to check all the conditions.

Comment: So try to implement your pseudo code and the ask for help to get it to work. You will get down voted (not by me) for not showing any effort.

Comment: Understand, but I think it is clear for the question that I asked. What I am trying to ask is a way to make the logic simple instead of checking every single condition. Or I shouldn't ask this type of question here because it is not related to programming?

Comment: You haven't state what you want to do for conditions 2,3,4. Depends on what you want to do, you may build your result from the input without checking any conditions. For example, if you want to combine the non-empty arrays, you can just combine all arrays since combining empty arrays does not affect anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```js
//initiate
var filterAResultArr= [1,2];
var filterBResultArr= [2,1];
var filterCResultArr = [1];
var filterDResultArr= [];
var filterSeResult = [];

// combine the array
var combine_array = [filterAResultArr, filterBResultArr,filterCResultArr,filterDResultArr];

// filter out the array is not empty
filterSeResult  = combine_array.filter(function( v ) {
   return v.length > 0;
});

// concat the result from array filter
// filterSeResult = pick_result.map(function(a) {
//   return filterSeResult.concat(a);
// });

console.log( filterSeResult );

// Result
/*
[
  [
    1,
    2
  ],
  [
    2,
    1
  ],
  [
    1
  ]
]

*/
```

```js
//initiate
var filterAResultArr= [1,2];
var filterBResultArr= [2,1];
var filterCResultArr = [1];
var filterDResultArr= [];
var filterSeResult = [];

// combine the array
var combine_array = [filterAResultArr, filterBResultArr,filterCResultArr,filterDResultArr];

// filter out the array is not empty
var pick_result = combine_array.filter(function( v ) {
   return v.length > 0;
});

// concat the result from array filter
filterSeResult = pick_result.reduce(function(a, b) {
   return a.concat(b);
}, []);

console.log( filterSeResult );

// Result
/*
[
  1,
  2,
  2,
  1,
  1
]

*/
```